# How can I verically center InputLabel inside MUI Grid item?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to vertically center `InputLabel` inside MUI `Grid` item.
I tried following:

```
import { FormControl, Grid, Input, InputLabel, TextField } from "@mui/material";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={2}>
        <InputLabel htmlFor="name-input">First Name: </InputLabel>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={10}>
        <TextField size="small"></TextField>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={2}>
        <InputLabel sx={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }} htmlFor="name-input">
          First Name:{" "}
        </InputLabel>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={10}>
        <TextField size="small"></TextField>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

But its not getting vertically aligned:

[image]

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-bush-3foin2?file=/src/App.js:0-604)

Note that setting `sx={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }}` in second `InputLabel` also doesnt help.

How one should (possibly ideally) vertically center `InputLabel` (or any other control) inside `Grid` item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

to the grid item divs it works.

I find this a useful flexbox explainer: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

I've added it to your sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-pascal-3rpokb?file=/src/App.js